# Turn 2 integers in to 1

Tags: python

I have a method that is retrieving a couple of random numbers. I then want to combine randoma and randomb to be one number

For example if randoma = 2 and randomb = 150, I want it to return 2150

I am unsure how to do so. The #'s are where my unknown return statement would be.

```
def display()
    total = setnums()
    print("total = " + total)

def setnums():
    randoma = random.randint(1, 5)
    randomb = random.randint(100,1000)
    return ########
```

Comment: use **struct** module of python . byte conversion

Answer (score 6):

In Python 3.6 and newer:

```py
int(f'{randoma}{randomb}')
```

In Python older than 3.6:

```py
int(str(randoma) + str(randomb))
```

Comment: That's pretty harsh to say that versions before 3.6 don't have any choice but to manually concatenate strings... You can use `str.format`, of which f-strings are juste syntactic sugar, or %-strings

Comment: I never said that there was no other choices, I gave the solution that was prettier at my eyes.

Answer (score 2):

Convert them to strings and concatenate them.

```
return int(str(randoma) + str(randomb))
```

Answer (score 0):

`int(str(randoma) + str(randomb))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it using simple mathematic without converting to string

```
from math import floor, log10, pow
from random import randint

def display():
    total = setnums()
    print(total)

def setnums():
     randoma = randint(1, 5)
     randomb = randint(100,1000)
     print(randoma)
     print(randomb)
     numberOfDigitsInFirstRandNumber = floor(log10(randomb))
     numberOfDigitsInSecondRandNumber = floor(log10(randomb))
     totalDigitCount =  numberOfDigitsInFirstRandNumber + numberOfDigitsInSecondRandNumber
     multiplyingFactor = pow(10, totalDigitCount - 1)
     return (randoma * multiplyingFactor ) + randomb

display()
```

Basically what you do is to sum the number of digits in both numbers, subtract one from it and raise 10 to the power of the result, then multiple the first random number by the result and add it to the second random number.

you can try it out from here https://repl.it/repls/StainedRashArchive

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**:

In Python >= 3.6 use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/):

```py
return int(f'{randoma}{randomb}')
```

In Python < 3.6 use the + Operator:

```py
int(str(randoma) + str(randomb))
```

Keep it simple, readable, and test in your own environment which option suits you best.

---

Given the following function:

```
def setnums():
    randoma = random.randint(1, 5)
    randomb = random.randint(100, 1000)
    r = ##
    return int(r)
```

**Execution time in python3.6:**

```py
r = f"{randoma}{randomb}"
2.870281131
```

```py
r = "%s%s" % (randoma, randomb)
2.9696586189999996
```

```py
r = str(randoma) + str(randomb)
3.084615994999999
```

```py
r = "".join((str(randoma), str(randomb)))
3.1661511100000013
```

```py
def setnums():
    randoma = str(random.randint(1, 5))
    randomb = str(random.randint(100, 1000))
    randoma += randomb
    return int(randoma)

3.0611202350000006
```

**Execution time in python2.7:**

```py
r = "%s%s" % (randoma, randomb)
2.46315312386
```

```py
r = str(randoma) + str(randomb)
2.56769394875
```

```py
r = "".join((str(randoma), str(randomb)))
2.68126797676
```

```py
def setnums():
    randoma = str(random.randint(1, 5))
    randomb = str(random.randint(100, 1000))
    randoma += randomb
    return int(randoma)

2.53426408768
```

---

[Literal String Interpolation (PEP 498)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).
[Splitting, Concatenating, and Joining Strings in Python](https://realpython.com/python-string-split-concatenate-join/)

Answer (score -2):

Use the 'str' function to convert randoma and randomb to strings, concatenate by using '=', then convert the concatenated string to integer by using the 'int' function.